# Copy rows from multiple sheets into one sheet based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy rows from multiple sheets into one combined sheet based on a cell valve.

Details:
I have multiple project numbers that are tabs (2016-010-082, 2016-010-086, 2016-060-015... etc).  In column E on each of these sheets I have a dropdown box where you can pick "yes" or "no" based on if this task is completed or not.  I would like where all the tasks that are "no", the row will copy over into a single sheet so I can see all the tasks for all the projects that are not yet completed.

When the "no" is changed to a "yes" on the specific project tab, I would like the row to be removed from the compiled sheet as well.

I would also like cells D2 and D3 from each show up in rows A and B of the compiled sheet as that is standard information for each tab that I will need to see on the compiled sheet so I know which project number it is and the project name.

Sample image.
[image: Sample Image]

This is what I thought would work for one sheet.

```
Sub Test()
    For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("E:E")
        If Cell.Value = "NO" Then
            matchRow = Cell.Row
            Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi can you show what work you have done so far to achieve this? This is a support site, not development site.

Comment: this is what I thought would work for one sheet... once I got this working simple one working properly I figured I could format it for multiple sheets...Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("E:E")
    If Cell.Value = "NO" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, where you want a list of just those facilities with "No", you can use this array formula (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

`=INDEX(B$2:B$4,SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$4="Yes",ROW(B$2:B$4)-ROW(B$2)+1),ROWS(B$2:B2)))`

Assuming your data is laid out like this:
[image]

Then, wrap `IfError([formula],"")` around that to hide the `#NUM` errors.  As you change "No" in "Completed" to "Yes", the list on the right will update.